# Creating an excel macro to check the column values and sum them together

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am new to excel macros and I need to create an excel macro which will check the first 4 characters of a number in a cell and if it matches the other 4 characters in a cell in a different columns then the values in a separate column need to be summed together and places at the first instance where the two numbers matches in a different column named LE Internal.

Example on link below
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1beh6.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIBSm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dict1 As Object
    Dim c1 As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim currWS As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, tot As Long
    Dim number1 As Long, number2 As Long, firstRow As Long

    Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set currWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") '-->change Sheet1 to your work sheet name

    'get last row withh data in Column A
    lastRow = currWS.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'put unique numbers in Column A in dict1
    c1 = Range("A2:B" & lastRow)
    For i = 1 To UBound(c1, 1)
        If c1(i, 1) <> "" Then
            'make combination with first 4 characters
            dict1(Left(c1(i, 1), 4) & "," & Left(c1(i, 2), 4)) = 1
        End If
    Next i

    'loop through all the numbers in column A
    For Each k In dict1.keys
        number1 = Split(k, ",")(0)
        number2 = Split(k, ",")(1)
        tot = 0
        firstRow = 0

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If k = Left(currWS.Range("A" & i).Value, 4) & "," & Left(currWS.Range("B" & i).Value, 4) Then
                If firstRow = 0 Then
                    firstRow = i
                End If
                tot = tot + currWS.Range("C" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
        currWS.Range("D" & firstRow) = tot
    Next k
End Sub
```

See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is there a way of changing the code to only look at the first 4 characters of column A and Column B? for example if number 1 had a number of 12434 and column b had a number of 12434 it would only look for the 1243?

Comment: @GeorgeHalford - Use `Set rFound = .Find(What:=Left(k, 4) & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)` instead of `Set rFound = .Find(What:=k, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

Comment: @GeorgeHalford - Can you show some sample data and desired output. I'll be able to answer better.

Comment: Thank you for your continued guidance, please see example 1 image attached to the question, as you can see it is summing only the values which appear in column A when in fact what I would like it to do is the Example 2 image attached to the question.

Comment: Example 2 is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @GeorgeHalford - Okay, so what you want is to compare `Column A` and `Column B` both and then add values?

Comment: Yeah, if column A and Column B do not match then I want the sum to still occur but if they match over multiple rows then I want a group sum as shown on Example 2.

Comment: @GeorgeHalford - Are you okay with formula using helper column?

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of doing this using a macro and not a formula with helper columns? I also want only to look at first 4 characters not the whole string.

Comment: @GeorgeHalford - See [image](https://i.imgur.com/kYKI600.png) and confirm this is how result should be on reading first 4 characters.

Comment: @GeorgeHalford - Or else if you can provide example that will be much better.

Comment: Yes your image is how I would like this to be laid out

Comment: Thank you, I have a new requirement hopefully you could help? I would like to compare two additional columns which are date columns like I have done previously.